# Firefox opens Profile Directory with SMPlayer

Tags: firefox, mime-type, smplayer

Each time I go to [about:support](http://about:support) and click on "Open Directory", Firefox opens it with SMPlayer and then mpv/mplayer complains about :

```
  Playing: /home/sebastien/.mozilla/firefox-esr/empty6/persdict.dat
Failed to recognize file format.
Exiting... (Errors when loading file)
```

So I've searched "smplayer" in [about:preferences#applications](http://about:preferences#applications) but couldn't find it.

I've also searched for "smplayer" in [about:config](http://about:config) but couldn't find it either.

And finally I've searched in the XDG mimes types definitions :

```bsh
$ xdg-mime query filetype ~/.mozilla/firefox-esr/empty6/persdict.dat
text/plain
$ xdg-mime query default text/plain
kate.desktop
$ xdg-mime query filetype ~/
inode/directory
$ xdg-mime query default inode/directory
dolphin.desktop
```

EDIT 0 : Adding a few `xdg-open` commands :

```bsh
$ xdg-open ~/.mozilla/firefox-esr/empty6/persdict.dat
Fontconfig warning: ignoring C.UTF-8: not a valid language tag
$ pgrep -af /persdict.dat
32659 /usr/bin/kate -b /home/sebastien/.mozilla/firefox-esr/empty6/persdict.dat
$ xdg-open Documents
Fontconfig warning: ignoring C.UTF-8: not a valid language tag
$ pgrep -af /Documents
8437 /usr/bin/dolphin --icon system-file-manager -caption Dolphin /home/sebastien/Documents
```

EDIT 1 : `inode/directory=` entry in `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` :

```bsh
$ grep inode/directory= ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
inode/directory=dolphin.desktop;smplayer.desktop;kde4-dolphin.desktop;vlc.desktop;caja-2.desktop;kde4-kfmclient_dir.desktop;kde4-gwenview.desktop;easytag.desktop;nemo.desktop;audacious-qt.desktop;Thunar-folder-handler.desktop;qmmp_cue.desktop;audacious.desktop;kde4-k4dirstat.desktop;pcmanfm.desktop;qmmp_dir.desktop;qmmp_enqueue.desktop;
inode/directory=dolphin.desktop
```

EDIT 2 : The Dolphin application launcher is not found by Firefox because it's in the `kde4` subfolder of `/usr/share/applications/` :

```bsh
$ locate /dolphin.desktop
/usr/share/applications/kde4/dolphin.desktop
```

Explanation : Firefox couldn't find `dolphin.desktop` in `/usr/share/applications/`, therefore it was using the next entry for `inode/directory` mimetype in `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` file which was `smplayer.desktop` :

```bsh
$ grep inode/directory= ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
inode/directory=dolphin.desktop;smplayer.desktop;kde4-dolphin.desktop;vlc.desktop;caja-2.desktop;kde4-kfmclient_dir.desktop;kde4-gwenview.desktop;easytag.desktop;nemo.desktop;audacious-qt.desktop;Thunar-folder-handler.desktop;qmmp_cue.desktop;audacious.desktop;kde4-k4dirstat.desktop;pcmanfm.desktop;qmmp_dir.desktop;qmmp_enqueue.desktop;
inode/directory=dolphin.desktop
```

Solution : Thanks to [ashvatthama's anwser](https://askubuntu.com/a/1251449/426176) : To solve this pb., you can type this command :

`xdg-mime default kde4-dolphin.desktop inode/directory`

and now it works fine :

```bsh
$ pgrep -af /empty6
29083 dolphin --icon system-file-manager -caption Dolphin /home/sebastien/.mozilla/firefox-esr/empty6
```

<s>I've seen this bug for years, I'd love to solve it.</s>

Can you help me ?

Comment: Please edit the question title to clearly reflect your question.

Comment: @vanadium Just edited the title, is it better ?

Comment: Try https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333254/set-standard-file-browser-for-open-containing-folder

Comment: Much clearer now - it puts the reader on the right foot. Strange issue, though.

Comment: If you would go to a terminal and give the command `xdg-open Documents`, would it also attempt to open Documents with SMPlayer?

Comment: @vanadium Nope, it opens the `Documents` folder with Dolphin

Comment: @vanadium Added EDIT0

Comment: Which version of which os?

Comment: @ashvatthama Added EDIT1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> $ grep inode/directory= ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
> inode/directory=dolphin.desktop;smplayer.desktop;kde4-dolphin.desktop;vlc.desktop;caja-2.desktop;kde4-kfmclient_dir.desktop;kde4-gwenview.desktop;easytag.desktop;nemo.desktop;audacious-qt.desktop;Thunar-folder-handler.desktop;qmmp_cue.desktop;audacious.desktop;kde4-k4dirstat.desktop;pcmanfm.desktop;qmmp_dir.desktop;qmmp_enqueue.desktop;
> inode/directory=dolphin.desktop
>
> $ grep inode/directory= /usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
> inode/directory=Thunar-folder-handler.desktop;kde4-kid3.desktop;kde4-gwenview.desktop;kde4-dolphin.desktop;kde4-kfmclient_dir.desktop;nautilus.desktop;caja-folder-handler.desktop;audacious-qt.desktop;nautilus-folder-handler.desktop;pcmanfm.desktop;audacious.desktop;baobab.desktop;nemo.desktop;
> ```

so what you should do is edit both of these files so that the lines starting with `inode/directory` say `inode/directory=dolphin.desktop` and nothing else.

### EDIT: subfolders

According to the [XDG Desktop Entry specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s02.html):

> #### Desktop File ID
>
> Each desktop entry representing an application is identified by its desktop file ID, which is based on its filename.
>
> To determine the ID of a desktop file, make its full path relative to the $XDG_DATA_DIRS component in which the desktop file is installed, remove the "applications/" prefix, and turn '/' into '-'.
>
> For example /usr/share/applications/foo/bar.desktop has the desktop file ID foo-bar.desktop.

so you didn't need to make a symlink from `dolphin.desktop` to `kde4/dolphin.desktop`, you could have just specified `kde4-dolphin.desktop` to `xdg-mime` etc.

Comment: You're right. But the thing is I have multiple desktop environments installed on this PC (KDE,XFCE,LXDE), each of them having their own default file managers.

Comment: I see, then at least you should remove the `smplayer.desktop` bit

Comment: Yes. I was trying to edit it and somehow it was being written by another daemon. Now, the file size is 0 so I'm going to remove it. Now, I've just re-defined the `inode/directory` to `dolphin.desktop` with this command : `xdg-mime default dolphin.desktop inode/directory`

Comment: did `xdg-mime default` fix the issue?

Comment: Yes and No. Yes because firefox does not use SMPlayer anymore but No because it does NOT use Dolphin either.

Comment: Can you understand why the first `desktop` application of `inode/directory=` is ignored even though it's present in the `/usr/share/applications/` folder ?

Comment: I'm not really sure. I guess 1) there's a cache overriding it (`mimeinfo.cache`) or 2) maybe it chooses the last in the list, instead of the first

Comment: Take a look at my EDIT2 :)

Comment: @SebMa Great to hear you solved it! but I don't think you need the symlink, see the edit to my answer.

Comment: Great solution :) ! Just removed my symlink and typed `xdg-mime default kde4-dolphin.desktop inode/directory` and now it works fine ! Wish I could upvote your answer a second time but it seems the Stack Exchange application does not allow it :(